# CommandError in Python for Discord bot

Tags: python, discord

```
import discord 
import os # To get token into our main code file we use os library 
import requests #makes http requests to get data in our case we get data from our API 
import json # API returns json 
import random # we use this for randomising inspiretion when user sends sad messages.
from replit import db # we use this to access repel.it's data base 

client = discord.Client() #instance to client it is connection to discord
# bellow is the function to genrate random new quotes with author name 
sad_words = ["sad", "depressedfrom replit import db", "unhappy", "miserable"] 
Cheer_up = [" Whoever is trying to bring you down, is already below you","You are awesome! Never forget that", "Forget what’s gone, appreciate what remains, and look forward what’s coming next"]

if "responding" not in db.keys(): #We create a new key in the database called "responding" and set it to "True". We'll use this to determine if the bot should respond to sad words or not.
  db["responding"] = True
#we only create the new key if it doesn't already exist.
def get_quote():
  response = requests.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random") # use to genrate random quotes
  json_data = json.loads(response.text) # Converting this response to json
  quote = json_data[0]['q'] + " " + json_data[0]['a'] # Here we are getting quotes from json in above line we loaded it here by ['q'] we get quotes and then we concatenate it with name of the author of the quote.
  return (quote)
def update_cheer_ups(cheering_up_message): # We are creating the function for udating encouragements.
  if "encouragements" in db.keys(): #Check if encouragements is key in the database 
    encouragements = db["encouragements"]
    encouragements.append(cheering_up_message) # adding new engcouragements to list
    db["encouragements"] = encouragements # updated encoragements to our data base of repl
  
  else:
    db[encouragements] = [cheering_up_message] # if there would not be any encouragements in database we will have to create it 

def delete_cheer_ups(index): #this function is for deleting cheeeing messages we require index for deleting cheering up messages
  encouragements = db["encouragements"] # Getting list of cheering up message messages from data base
  if len(encouragements) > index: # Check if entered index value is valid for getting message index should be > message
    del encouragements[index]  # deleteing the cheering message 
    db["encouragements"] = encouragements # updated to database with changes
@client.event #register an event
# This library has lots of events 

# This library is asyncrones library so this works on call back function
# Call back function means it occurs only when somthing occurs in our case
# Program bellow has on_ready & on_message are events 
# This events makes the call back function run

async def on_ready(): # Called when bot is ready to get used
  print("we have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))
  # Here we are replacing 0 wiht client to get user
@client.event # agian registering the event before any other is called 
async def on_message(message): # This is called when bot recives any message
  
  msg = message.content

  if msg == client.user: # we have to make sure that we ignore messages from ourselves. We do this by checking if the Message.author is the same as the Client.user. 
    return
  if msg.startswith('inspire!'): # When someone uses the command $hello then our bot sends the message which is below
    quote = get_quote()
    await message.channel.send(quote)
  
  options = Cheer_up

  if db["responding"]: #section that responds to sad words is now inside this if statement
    options = Cheer_up
    if "encouragements" in db.keys():
      options = options + db["encouragements"]


  if "encouragements" in db.keys():
    options = options + db[encouragements]

  if msg.startswith('hello!'): # When someone uses the commad $hello then our bot sends the message which is bellow
    await message.channel.send('Hello welcome to my server')

  if any(word in msg for word in sad_words): # Here we are we created that id anyone writes sad word from list of sad words our bot will cheer user by taking quotes from Cheer_up.
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(options))
  
  if msg.startswith("new!"): # Command to add new message to data base 
    cheering_up_message = msg.split("new! ", 1)[1] # here we store message afte new! command to data base here we get every thing in array so we use [1] to call message because message would be 2nd element of array 
    update_cheer_ups(cheering_up_message) # Updating message which is given by user
    await message.channel.send("New encouraging message learn't") # just letting user know that his given encoraging message is stored 
  if msg.startswith("del!"):
    encouragements = [] # First a new variable called encouragements is initialized as an empty array. The reason for this is that this section of code will send a message with an empty array if the database does not include an "encouragement" key.
    if "encouragements" in db.keys(): # checking if encouragement key exist's
      index = int(msg.split("$del",1)[1]) #If the "encouragement" key is in the database, the index will be split off from the Discord message starting with "$del"
      delete_encouragment(index) # Then, the delete_encouragement() function is called passing in the index to delete.
      encouragements = db["encouragements"] # he updated list of encouragements is loaded into the encouragements variable, and then the bot sends a message to Discord with the current list.
    await message.channel.send(encouragements)
  
  if msg.startswith("$list"):
    encouragements = []
    if "encouragements" in db.keys():
      encouragements = db["encouragements"]
    await message.channel.send(encouragements)
    
  if msg.startswith("$responding"):
    value = msg.split("$responding ",1)[1]

    if value.lower() == "true":
      db["responding"] = True # The bot will only respond to sad words if it is true like in this line right here. The ability to update this value comes after this next section.
      await message.channel.send("Responding is on.")
    else:
      db["responding"] = False
      await message.channel.send("Responding is off.")


client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
# This client.run is to run the bot we put our bot's token which is genrated during it's creation.
# Token acts as password of bot it should not been shared 
# we did not pasted token here because in repl.it we creat .env extinsion file to make our token hidden 
# os.getenv is used to access the token from env file
# it not nessury to use TOKEN it just like variable 

# when we are doing this localy we do not need .env file to use token we can normaly paste token here in repl we are doing publical that is why it is env and os to access token from env.
```

1. This code is for Discord bot which contains commands like "hello!"(bot greets on this command), "inspire!"(bot gives random inspiration quotes on this command), "new!"(if any user want's to add his own encouraging quotes or statements) , "del!"(if user add something wrong in new! command then user can use del! command to delete it).
2. Bot also throws some inspirational quotes when user writes some sad words from our "sad_words" named list.
3. I am facing an issue when new! command is tried to use it is supposed to throw confirmation that "New encouraging message learn't" but it does not happen to be working.
4. I am not able to get how can i solve it
5. Comments in code will explain whole code
6. Error right bellow:
   [image: error image]

Comment: "Inline comments are unnecessary and in fact distracting if they state the obvious."–PEP 8

Comment: no actually i am learning so this would be a reference code for me so that's why this is not a project i am just learning

Comment: That is something to learn: Commenting obvious things is actually more distracting than helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've missed quotes when accessing `db`'s key `'encouragements'` at line 28:

```
db['encouragements'] = [cheering_up_message]
```

Comment: @NimeshJoshi It is not. You define `encouragements` variable inside `if`. It won't exist if condition was falsy.